# How to find this asymptotics?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

In my research I need to find the asymptotics of the integral
$$\int\limits_2^\infty r^xe^{\log^2 x -\log x - x\sqrt{\log x}}\,dx ,\, r\to \infty.$$
I don't succeed to apply Theorem 2.3 from [M. Fedoryuk. The saddle-point method. Nauka. Moscow, 1977](https://zbmath.org/?q=py:1977%20ai:fedoryuk.mikhail-v).
In order to apply it, an exact asymptotics of the solution $x(r)$ of the equation 
$$\frac {2\log x-1} x  -\log^{\frac 1 2} x - \frac 1 {2\log^{\frac 1 2}x}+\log r=0$$ 
as $r \to \infty$ is required. The asymptotics $\log x(r) \thicksim \log ^2 r$ is not sufficiently exact to this end.

Comment: For large $x$ resp. $r$ the first term is much smaller than the second and third term. If you neglect the first term and solve the corresponding quadratic equation you get

$
log(x(r)) \approx \left(\frac{log(r)+\sqrt{log^2(r)-2}}{2}\right)^2 \approx log(r)^2-1+O(log(r)^{-2}).
$

Comment: @user35593: Thank you, your suggestion is useful.

Comment: MSE is a right place for such type questions...